# The paradox of odds for the 2017 World Series

Tags: probability

I have been tracking the progression of odds of winning for the Houston Astros and Los Angeles Dodgers in the ongoing World Series, and the latest odds after the results of Game 5 have me puzzled.

Here is the full set of percentages for both teams from before the series began to today. The first column is that team's record in the series, then each following column is their chance of winning the series in however many games.

First, the Astros. You can see their odds of winning in seven games were much higher than their odds of winning in four games, which is reasonable enough.

```
Astros  IN 4    IN 5    IN 6    IN 7
0-0     4.60%   6.30%   13.90%  16.60%
0-1     xxx     4.30%   11.20%  13.20%
1-1     xxx     10.00%  17.00%  17.10%
2-1     xxx     18.20%  24.50%  19.00%
2-2     xxx     xxx     18.30%  20.30%
3-2     xxx     xxx     47.00%  24.00%
```

Next we have the Dodgers' odds. They were favored, so their odds of winning in each combination were initially better.

```
Dodgers IN 4    IN 5    IN 6    IN 7
0-0     7.50%   19.20%  17.60%  14.30%
1-0     14.50%  22.20%  18.90%  15.80%
1-1     xxx     16.00%  20.20%  19.70%
1-2     xxx     xxx     16.50%  21.80%
2-2     xxx     xxx     32.10%  29.30%
2-3     xxx     xxx     xxx     29.00%
```

But here's the odd part. Let's look at the most recent odds. There are three possibilities remaining: The Astros win in 6, the Astros win in 7, and the Dodgers win in 7. So the total chance that the Astros win is 47% + 24% = 71%, and the Dodgers chance is 29%. So clearly the Astros are highly favored to win it all at this point.

But wait! Since the Astros only have a 47% chance of winning in six, that means the odds are they won't win in six. So if we look at the remaining percentages, which add up to 53%, it looks like the Dodgers have a 29/53 = 54.7% chance to win, while the Astros have a 24/53 = 45.3% chance to win. So it looks like the reality is the Dodgers are favored.

Am I cheating here, since these are simply gambling odds makers, or is there a way to make sense of this mathematically with probabilities?

Comment: The Dodgers have 29% chance to win it all which is clearly less than 71%. Dividing 29% by 53% makes no sense as 29% is the probability that LA wins in 7 and 53% is the probability that Houston does not win in 6. We already have the probability that LA wins in 7 and it's not 54.7%

Comment: @Vasya but my point is these aren't all simultaneously possibilities. Game 6 must happen first, then (if necessary) game 7.

Comment: See, the current odds are the odds of three mutually exclusive events but one of them has to happen so if you add 3 probabilities you get 100%. Dodgers win in 7 is depending on Houston losing game 6, if Houston wins that probability goes to zero. From the current odds we can see that probability of LA winning game 6 is about 0.53. This means that the probability of LA winning two games in a row is $0.53 \cdot 0.53$ which is about 0.28 (this assume that the probability winning one particular game stays the same)

Comment: You've calculated two things: First, the probability that Houston wins the series is $71\%$. Second, the conditional probability that Houston wins the series **if** they lose game $6$ is only $45.3\%$. There's nothing strange about this; losing game $6$ certainly should reduce Houston's chances of winning the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analogy: let's say that I roll a fair 10-sided die and call the result $X$. I'm interested in two events: $A = \{X \text{ is } 1,\ 2, \text{ or } 3\}$ and $B = \{X \text{ is bigger than }3\}$. Note that $B$ is overwhelmingly more likely than $A$; specifically, $P(B) = 0.7$ and $P(A) = 0.3$. But if I restrict to the event $C = \{X \text{ is at most }4\}$, now $B$ is suddenly much less likely; specifically, $B$ now has a $1/4$ chance of occurring, and $A$ has a $3/4$ chance of occurring.

What's really happening in both examples is that $P(B) > P(A)$, but $P(B| C) < P(A | C)$. There's no inconsistency with that.

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense. You typed "Note that B is overwhelmingly more likely than AB". Did you mean "Note that B is overwhelmingly more likely than A"?

Comment: Oops! Yes, that was a silly typo on my part. I'll edit.